# Is there a way to require tox to always update dependencies to the latest version?

Tags: python, tox

Is there a way to ask tox to always upgrade dependencies to the latest? For example:

```
[testenv:test]
deps = package-nightly
```

I would like to make sure that the latest nightly version is downloaded every time I start the `test` environment, but I don't want to reinstall if there's no upgrade. Perhaps requiring to to run `pip install -U` every time can do but I'm unsure.

Comment: you could add a `pip install --upgrade` command as one of your `commands=`

Comment: `recreate=true` to force `tox` to recreate every environment.

Comment: @phd this will not work, it will use locally cached pip packages (on linux ~/.cache/pip) when they meet the version requirements, even then newer versions are released.